# Program that types pre set things for me

Tags: gratis

I like to solve killer sudoku puzzles online and I find myself typing every number in a cell a lot. I am wondering if anyone knows a program that I can set to type them all out quickly when I input a command, like an auto clicker for the keyboard.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[**AutoHotkey**](https://www.autohotkey.com/) can be used to send keyboard input. (See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s3).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Firefox**, then use can use **GreaseMonkey** to make up scripts.

For **Chrome** there is **Tampermonkey** or **AceScript**.